# apollo watch method with variables

Tags: apollo-client

I am trying to use apollo client watch method in angular to query spring boot server. I am not able to pass arguments with this method.
Since  "aid" is mandatory, when it is trying to make a call I getting error like 
ERROR Error: GraphQL error: Variable 'aid' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'String!'

Below is my code in typescript.

```
export class AgreementGQL extends Query {
  document = gql`query agreement($aid: String!) {
    agreement(id: $aid) {
      id      
      name
    }
  }
```

Below is calling code to the agreement. Where agreement is injected in constructor.

```
this.agreement.watch({
        aid: "1234567"
      }).valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
      console.log("*********** result : " + JSON.stringify(result.data));
    });
```

I tried using "variables" as well, but no luck.

```
this.agreement.watch({ variables:{
        aid: "1234567"
      }}).valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
      console.log("*********** result : " + JSON.stringify(result.data));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the value as a key/value pair like:

```
const myVal = '123';
```

Then pass that as an object into the watch method...

```
const agreement = this.agreementQuery
  .watch({ myVal })
  .valueChanges.pipe(pluck('data'));
```

Then Subscribe to get the data out:

```
 agreement.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

This approach worked for me.